# Erro de Publicação no Spring

Tags: eclipse, spring, tomcat

Estou tendo problema com esta nova versão do Spring sts.

```
Version: 3.6.1.RELEASE 
Build Id: 201408250818
Platform: Eclipse Luna (4.4)
```

Estou usando sistema operacional Linux(Ubuntu)

Ttinha os meus projetos funcionando bem na versão anterior do Spring sts fui atualizar o meu sistema operacional para versão mais recente. Agora não consigo rodar os meus projetos.

Toda vez que tento executar o projeto com TomCat aparece o erro como se não estivesse encontrando os arquivo...

```
 Publishing failed with multiple errors
File not found: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/webcom/target/m2e-wtp/web-resources/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF.
File not found: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/webcom/target/m2e-wtp/web-resources/META-INF/maven/br.com/webcom/pom.properties.
File not found: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/webcom/target/m2e-wtp/web-resources/META-INF/maven/br.com/webcom/pom.xml.
File not found: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/webcom/target/classes/br/com/webcom/controller/HomeController.class.
File not found: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/webcom/target/classes/br/com/webcom/controller/PessoaController.class.
File not found: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/webcom/target/classes/br/com/webcom/controller/ProdutoController.class.
File not found: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/webcom/target/classes/br/com/webcom/dao/GenericDAO.class.
File not found: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/webcom/target/classes/br/com/webcom/dao/PessoaDAO.class.
File not found: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/webcom/target/classes/br/com/webcom/dao/ProdutoDAO.class.
File not found: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/webcom/target/classes/br/com/webcom/entity/Pessoa.class.
File not found: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/webcom/target/classes/br/com/webcom/entity/Produto.class.
File not found: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/webcom/target/classes/br/com/webcom/service/impl/PessoaServiceImpl.class.
File not found: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/webcom/target/classes/br/com/webcom/service/impl/ProdutoServiceImpl.class.
File not found: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/webcom/target/classes/br/com/webcom/service/PessoaService.class.
File not found: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/webcom/target/classes/br/com/webcom/service/ProdutoService.class.
File not found: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/webcom/target/classes/log4j.xml.
File not found: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/webcom/target/classes/persistence.properties.
File not found: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/webcom/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate/hibernate-validator-5.1.1.Final.jar.
File not found: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/webcom/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate/hibernate-validator-annotation-processor-5.1.1.Final.jar.
File not found: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/webcom/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate/hibernate-validator-cdi-5.1.1.Final.jar.
File not found: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/webcom/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml.
File not found: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/webcom/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/servlet-context.xml.
File not found: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/webcom/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/spring-security.xml.
File not found: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/webcom/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/home.jsp.
File not found: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/webcom/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/pessoa/pessoaForm.jsp.
File not found: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/webcom/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/pessoa/pessoaListar.jsp.
File not found: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/webcom/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/produto/produtoForm.jsp.
File not found: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/webcom/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/produto/produtoListar.jsp.
File not found: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/webcom/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/templating/head.jsp.
File not found: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/webcom/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/templating/navegation.jsp.
File not found: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/webcom/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml.
File not found: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/webcom/src/main/webapp/login.jsp.
File not found: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/webcom/src/main/webapp/resources/css/bootstrap-theme.css.
File not found: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/webcom/src/main/webapp/resources/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css.
File not found: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/webcom/src/main/webapp/resources/css/bootstrap.css.
File not found: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/webcom/src/main/webapp/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css.
File not found: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/webcom/src/main/webapp/resources/css/style.css.
File not found: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/webcom/src/main/webapp/resources/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot.
File not found: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/webcom/src/main/webapp/resources/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg.
File not found: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/webcom/src/main/webapp/resources/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf.
File not found: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/webcom/src/main/webapp/resources/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff.
File not found: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/webcom/src/main/webapp/resources/img/apple-touch-icon-114-precomposed.png.
File not found: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/webcom/src/main/webapp/resources/img/apple-touch-icon-144-precomposed.png.
File not found: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/webcom/src/main/webapp/resources/img/apple-touch-icon-57-precomposed.png.
File not found: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/webcom/src/main/webapp/resources/img/apple-touch-icon-72-precomposed.png.
File not found: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/webcom/src/main/webapp/resources/img/favicon.png.
File not found: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/webcom/src/main/webapp/resources/img/glyphicons-halflings-white.png.
File not found: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/webcom/src/main/webapp/resources/img/glyphicons-halflings.png.
File not found: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/webcom/src/main/webapp/resources/js/bootstrap.min.js.
File not found: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/webcom/src/main/webapp/resources/js/html5shiv.js.
File not found: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/webcom/src/main/webapp/resources/js/jquery.min.js.
File not found: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/webcom/src/main/webapp/resources/js/less-1.3.3.min.js.
File not found: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/webcom/src/main/webapp/resources/js/scripts.js.
File not found: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/webcom/src/main/webapp/resources/less/alerts.less.
File not found: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/webcom/src/main/webapp/resources/less/badges.less.
File not found: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/webcom/src/main/webapp/resources/less/bootstrap.less.
File not found: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/webcom/src/main/webapp/resources/less/breadcrumbs.less.
File not found: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/webcom/src/main/webapp/resources/less/button-groups.less.
File not found: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/webcom/src/main/webapp/resources/less/buttons.less.
File not found: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/webcom/src/main/webapp/resources/less/carousel.less.
File not found: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/webcom/src/main/webapp/resources/less/close.less.
File not found: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/webcom/src/main/webapp/resources/less/code.less.
File not found: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/webcom/src/main/webapp/resources/less/component-animations.less.
File not found: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/webcom/src/main/webapp/resources/less/dropdowns.less.
File not found: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/webcom/src/main/webapp/resources/less/forms.less.
File not found: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/webcom/src/main/webapp/resources/less/glyphicons.less.
File not found: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/webcom/src/main/webapp/resources/less/grid.less.
File not found: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/webcom/src/main/webapp/resources/less/input-groups.less.
File not found: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/webcom/src/main/webapp/resources/less/jumbotron.less.
File not found: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/webcom/src/main/webapp/resources/less/labels.less.
File not found: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/webcom/src/main/webapp/resources/less/list-group.less.
File not found: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/webcom/src/main/webapp/resources/less/media.less.
File not found: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/webcom/src/main/webapp/resources/less/mixins.less.
File not found: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/webcom/src/main/webapp/resources/less/modals.less.
File not found: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/webcom/src/main/webapp/resources/less/navbar.less.
File not found: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/webcom/src/main/webapp/resources/less/navs.less.
File not found: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/webcom/src/main/webapp/resources/less/normalize.less.
File not found: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/webcom/src/main/webapp/resources/less/pager.less.
File not found: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/webcom/src/main/webapp/resources/less/pagination.less.
File not found: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/webcom/src/main/webapp/resources/less/panels.less.
File not found: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/webcom/src/main/webapp/resources/less/popovers.less.
File not found: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/webcom/src/main/webapp/resources/less/print.less.
File not found: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/webcom/src/main/webapp/resources/less/progress-bars.less.
File not found: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/webcom/src/main/webapp/resources/less/responsive-utilities.less.
File not found: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/webcom/src/main/webapp/resources/less/scaffolding.less.
File not found: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/webcom/src/main/webapp/resources/less/tables.less.
File not found: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/webcom/src/main/webapp/resources/less/theme.less.
File not found: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/webcom/src/main/webapp/resources/less/thumbnails.less.
File not found: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/webcom/src/main/webapp/resources/less/tooltip.less.
File not found: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/webcom/src/main/webapp/resources/less/type.less.
File not found: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/webcom/src/main/webapp/resources/less/utilities.less.
File not found: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/webcom/src/main/webapp/resources/less/variables.less.
File not found: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/webcom/src/main/webapp/resources/less/wells.less.
```

---

tentei criar o projeto do zero mesmo assim aparece o erro 
file-> new-> project maven->spring-mvc-archetype

mesmo assim nao consigo rodar o projeto com tomcat

aparece o erro

```
Publishing failed with multiple errors
File not found: /opt/apache-tomcat-
.0.5/webapps/webcom/target/classes/br/com/webcom/config/MvcConfiguration.class.
File not found: /opt/apache-tomcat
0.55/webapps/webcom/target/classes/br/com/webcom/controller/HomeController.class.
File not found: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/webcom/src/main/webapp/WEB-
NF/views/home.jsp.
File not found: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/webcom/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml.
File not found: /opt/apache-tomcat-
.0.55/webapps/webcom/src/main/webapp/resources/style.css.
```

Comment: Tu ta usando maven?

Comment: sim estou usando maven

Comment: Já tentou apagar a pasta de cache do Maven, executar um `mvn clean install` e depois um `mvn package`?

Comment: deu o mesmo erro, nao resolvido

Comment: formatei a maquina se podia ser alguma coisa referente mas nada... estou usando java 1.8

Comment: Tente apagar as informções referentes ao projeto no tomcat

Answer (score 0):

Parece que tem algum lixo no seu projeto. Tenta implantar o seu .war na mão. Se funcionar então você deve apagar os arquivos que o eclipse cria no seu projeto (.classpath, .project, etc...) e importe seu projeto novamente.